# How should NotifierProvider be rewritten when StateNotifierClass is changed to NotifierClass?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have changed the `StateNotifier` class to a `Notifier` class, but I don't know how to rewrite `Provider`. Because my `StateNotifier` class uses as instance variables the values that other Providers observe. How can I use values observed by other Providers in `NotifierProvider`?

Newly created `NotifierClass`:

```dart
class CommunityController extends Notifier<bool> {
  final CommunityRepository _communityRepository;
  final StorageRepository _storageRepository;
  final Ref _ref;
  CommunityController({
    required CommunityRepository communityRepository,
    required StorageRepository storageRepository,
    required Ref ref,
  })  : _communityRepository = communityRepository,
        _storageRepository = storageRepository,
        _ref = ref;

  @override
  bool build() {
    return false;
  }

  void createCommunity(String name, BuildContext context) async {
    state = true;
    final uid = _ref.read(userProvider)?.uid ?? '';
    Community community = Community(
      id: name,
      name: name,
      banner: Constants.bannerDefault,
      avatar: Constants.avatarDefault,
      members: [uid],
      mods: [uid],
    );

    final res = await _communityRepository.createCommunity(community);
    state = false;
    res.fold((l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message), (r) {
      showSnackBar(context, 'Community created successfully!');
      Routemaster.of(context).pop();
    });
  }

  Stream<Community> getCommunityByName(String name) {
    return _communityRepository.getCommunityByName(name);
  }
}
```

`StateNotifierProvider` to be rewritten to `NotifierProvider`:

```
final communityControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CommunityController, bool>((ref) {
  final communityRepository = ref.watch(communityRepositoryProvider);
  final storageRepository = ref.watch(storageRepositoryProvider);
  return CommunityController(
    communityRepository: communityRepository,
    storageRepository: storageRepository,
    ref: ref,
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```dart
class CommunityNotifier extends Notifier<bool> {
  late final CommunityRepository _communityRepository;
  late final StorageRepository _storageRepository;

  @override
  bool build() {
    _communityRepository = ref.watch(communityRepositoryProvider);
    _storageRepository = ref.watch(storageRepositoryProvider);
    return false;
  }

}

// using tear-off
final communityNotifier = NotifierProvider<CommunityNotifier, bool>(CommunityNotifier.new);
```

In the `build` method you can safely use `ref.listen` and `ref.watch` and your `CommunityController` will have the correct dependencies.

---

**Bonus**: `Ref` no longer needs to be passed. We inherit it from the `Notifier` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I fixed my NotifierClass. However, I got an error in the "Controller.new" part of the communityControllerProvider. It says "The argument type 'CommunityController Function({required CommunityRepository communityRepository, required Ref<Object?> ref, required StorageRepository storageRepository})' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CommunityController Function()'." . Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @wasa-bi Remove your constructor in `CommunityController` completely, or use the normal way of creating a provider without tear-off